# How to decrease Docx4j load time

Tags: android, docx4j

I am using docx4j library to create/open/edit docx file. But it takes around 30 seconds to initialize this line

```
 wordMLPackage           = (WordprocessingMLPackage)loader.get(file);
```

It takes same time either it simple document(may be empty or single word/line file) or complex document  with images and tables.
I have increased memory for eclipse in eclipse.ini and VMHeap for emulator but no effect .It is slow on emulator as well as on real device. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See forum post [wordprocessingmlpackage-load-file-is-extremely-slow](http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/the-wordprocessingmlpackage-load-file-is-extremely-slow-t440.html)

The JAXB context init time is unavoidable (unless you remove some of the packages listed, or hack your JAXB implementation to do some funky on demand type loading), but only needs to be done once.

Comment: Yes it takes time on first load, but not sure which package should i remove. I am using this library to create/open/edit docx file.Can you suggest me any packages that i can remove.